# calculate transition matrix for multiple sequences in matrix

Tags: r, matrix, transition, markov-chains, markov

Hi guys i am trying to calculate transition matrix for every sequences which is presented by each row in a matrix. For example, i have a matrix:

```
    dat<-matrix(c('a','b','c','a','a','a','b','b','a','c','a','a','c','c','a'),nrow = 3)

   > `
        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
    [1,] "a"  "a"  "b"  "c"  "c" 
    [2,] "b"  "a"  "b"  "a"  "c" 
    [3,] "c"  "a"  "a"  "a"  "a" `
```

I can easily calculate transition matrix for a single row using

```
    > `mylistMc<-markovchainFit(data=dat[1,])`
```

I get a correct result

```
    > `      
     a   b  c
        a 0.5 0.5 0
        b 0.0 0.0 1
        c 0.0 0.0 1`
```

Then i tried to use

```
    > `mc<-markovchainListFit(data=dat[1,])`
```

But the results are weird, it gives 4 matrixes instead of 3 (i suppose it takes columns instead of rows maybe), i believe MarkovChainListFit is used for a multiple sequences, and i just don't getting how to use it.
Any ideas guys? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
mc <- apply(t(dat),2,function(x) markovchainFit(x))
trans_mat <- list(mc[[1]][[1]],mc[[2]][[1]],mc[[3]][[1]])
```

Comment: Why should I, the OP, or anyone else for that matter "try this"? Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post (such as yourself, answering 2 years after it was originally asked).